# $RANDOM in sleep

Tags: scripts

I'm trying to get my script to pause randomly between 20 and 10 seconds where the max amount of time is 20 and minimum 10. I'm using this atm:

```
sleep $((10 + RANDOM % 20));
```

But the problem is that it disregards the limit of 20 and goes beyond that.
Is there an other way?

Comment: `RANDOM % 20` will yield a number between 0 and 20. Add 10 to it and you will get a number between 10 and 30. You probably mean `$((10 + RANDOM % 10))`.

Answer (score 15):

10 and 20 are not min and max of the RANDOM number. 
The expression is simple math. `%` means modulo.

You want

```
sleep $((10 + RANDOM % 11));
```

It's `11` because 10-20 are 11 numbers.

---

Alternatively, you could use `shuf`:

```
sleep $(shuf -i 10-20 -n 1)
```

Comment: Thanks again dude! you helped me allot today :) but quick question what does the 1 means at the end with shuf?

Comment: `-n 1` limits the output to 1 line. It otherwise prints all possible values.

Answer (score -1):

for sleeping random milliseconds

```
t=$(shuf -i 0-9 -n1)

sleep 0."$t"
```

Comment: I think your answer does not address the specific question, and it could otherwise also benefit from more explanation on what exactly you are suggesting and why. As it stands, your command will sleep for one of 0, 100, 200, ... 900 ms, and is incompatible with the range the OP asked about.